# How to start views at %nid position (from path)?

Tags: uri, javascript, views

I have a portfolio showing somes nodes (views3 + views slideshow using cycle). Everything works fine, I've a default path `/portfolio` to access to it.

However, I'm trying to set a path for each slide. I would like to use `/portfolio/%nid` and using `%nid` in views to default the first viewed slide to this node id.

Anyone know how it is possible ? I've tried with UI but I don't think it is enough.

Answer (score 1):

In [jQuery Cycle there is an option](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) called startingSlide. By default this is set to 0, like this: startingSlide: 0

If I remember correctly there is a tab/textarea for advanced settings where you can add options to jQuery Cycle from within the Views UI. I think you can add "startingSlide: 5" for example there.

You will need to find out which is the starting slide (convert the %nid to which row in the view it is) and add it as a HTML element. When that is in place we can fetch it with jQuery and add it as a jQuery Cycle option. I'm not sure which is the best way but I think you could do something like:

```
    function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
      if($view->name == "MYVIEW") {
        $view->attachment_after = $startingslide;
      }
    }
```

You will have to add more code to find out $startingslide there of course. Look inside $view->result and find out which of the rows that is the argument, that will be your $startingslide. Use dpm() on the view to search through the object.

Hope this will help you. Let me know what you ended up doing :)

Answer (score 0):

You could add an exposed filter to your view, configure it to show nids `greater than` the provided value, and mimic it's URL accordingly.

for example /portfolio?nid_is_greater_than=3

You could then hide your filter with css.

Comment: I'd use an argument (contextual filter) rather than an exposed filter - unless there are already arguments in use and this extra one would mess with the handling of those.

Comment: I know of no way to _compare_ a field value to a contextual filter value.

Comment: Good point. Must have been half-asleep when I posted the previous comment, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Since your problem is about appearance, not about structure I suggest to not solve it on the server and not in the URL path but on the client with a URL fragement: /portfolio#slide-[nid].

I've not read the javascript code of views slideshow + cycle, but I guess it's quite easy to adopt it's behavior to read the URL fragment on initialization of the slideshow. Or maybe there is already such a logic implemented which you could use...

Answer (score 0):

How about using 'Rewrite Output Results' option in Fields section of Views?

1. In Views, go to Configure (Image) Field > Rewrite Results
2. Check the 'Output this field as a link' checkbox
3. Enter the Link Path (nid/) and other details
4. Click on Apply
5. Save View

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Views passes off the display to `node_view()` in that case, and doesn't get involved with the markup for the row.

The easiest way to do what you want is to implement `hook_preprocess_node()`, look for a View in the current context, and if the node is being rendered as part of that display, you can make some alterations.

TAKE A LOOK AT THIS:

```
function MYMODULE_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['view']) && $vars['view']->view_name == 'foo') {
    $nid = $vars['node']->nid;
    $vars['extra_link'] = l('Some text', "node/$nid");
  }
}
```

In your `node.tpl.php` file you'll have access to `$extra_link.`